# How to hide server-side API in Backbone from the user?

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, server, single-page-application

To my understanding, we usually separate model from the view, and it includes all the calls to the server API. In example below, "/data" is where everyone can have access and call it.

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/data',
}
```

So generally, we are giving a hint to the user where to look for the data. Are there any mechanism, or set of guidelines to hide this from the user?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You can never rely on a browser to be well-behaved since you are in practice running your application on the end-users computer where they can take full control over it. Any attempts you make to hide the details of your server API can be circumvented and is therefore not a viable security mechanism.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can reliably make requests to your server from someone else's computer without them knowing. If they wants to know, they'll know. It's their computer...

Comment: I don't even have to look into the source code - I could use the application an monitor the network traffic. Forget it, it's security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

Setup two servers, one webserver will proxy the client request to the database server which will execute the "real" requests.

Comment: What exactly does that accomplish?

Comment: it would hide the real api of your application